# When I check sass version in terminal at vscode it shows an error

Tags: sass

I downloaded sass in my terminal. It is running successfully, but when i check the version it shows an error like:

```
 The term 'saas' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or  
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ saas -v
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (saas:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Is it saas or sass?

Comment: SaaS is not SASS